# How to get multiple selected image value and how to make JSON response in that selected value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here i am doing multiple image upload , suppose user click the one image, and again he want to add more image means he will click add more button then he can able to select multiple images,after that i want move the images in temporary folder, in normal php it is working fine,check below i shared the code,**My question is after selecting the all images (USER) i want to take the values and i want to make one JSON format** ,Please see below down i posted my expected JSON ,if anyone know means update my answer please i tried lot but not able to do

```js
var abc = 0;      // Declaring and defining global increment variable.
$(document).ready(function() {
//  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
$('#add_more').click(function() {
$(this).before($("<span/>", {
id: 'filediv'
}).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
name: 'file[]',
type: 'file',
id: 'file'
}), $(" ")));
});


// Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
abc += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1.
var z = abc - 1;
var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
$(this).before("<span id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></span>");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
$(this).hide();
$("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
id: 'img',
src: 'x.png',
alt: 'delete'
}).click(function() {
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
}));
}
});


// To Preview Image
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
$('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

// Form Submit
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var firstName = $("#firstName").val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var formData = new FormData($('#multipleImageForm')[0]);
    formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url :"test.php",
      data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(data);
        if(res['status'] == "Success"){
         $('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
                             $('#linzz').hide();
            $('#rentSuccess').show();
            setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "rent.php"; 
            }, 4000);
        }
       },
     error:function(exception){
     alert('Exeption:'+exception);
    }
    });

});
});
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans";
form{
background-color:#fff
}
#maindiv{
width:960px;
margin:10px auto;
padding:10px;
font-family:'Droid Sans',sans-serif
}
#formdiv{
width:500px;
float:left;
text-align:center
}
form{
padding:40px 20px;
box-shadow:0 0 10px;
border-radius:2px
}
h2{
margin-left:30px
}
.upload{
background-color:red;
border:1px solid red;
color:#fff;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 green;
box-shadow:2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
.upload:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background:#c20b0b;
border:1px solid #c20b0b;
box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
}
#file{
color:green;
padding:5px;
border:1px dashed #123456;
background-color:#f9ffe5
}
#upload{
margin-left:45px
}
#noerror{
color:green;
text-align:left
}
#error{
color:red;
text-align:left
}
#img{
width:17px;
border:none;
height:17px;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-bottom:91px
}
.abcd{
text-align:center
}
.abcd img{
height:100px;
width:100px;
padding:5px;
border:1px solid #e8debd
}
b{
color:red
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Multiple Images Using jquery and PHP</title>
<!-------Including jQuery from Google ------>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
<div id="maindiv">
<div id="formdiv">
<h2>Multiple Image Upload Form</h2>
<form method="post" id="multipleImageForm">
First Name: <input type="text" name ="firstName" id="firstName"><br><br><br>


<div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"  multiple/></div>
<input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Expected JSON (I want to make)**

```
{
"rentProperty" : {
    "firstName" : "some name"
}
"gallery": [
        {
            "image": "1.png"
        },
        {
            "image": "2.png"
        }
],
}
```

Comment: Do you have example in https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: No,you are understanding my question bro ?